# PowerShell: Short way to find String in Object-List with "Select-String"

Tags: powershell, grep, select-string

## Problem

I'm trying to find a way to find a string in a object list, like the result of `Get-Alias`. My problem is that all solutions are either way too long to be practical to use or do not result in the behavior I need.

### What I've tried so far:

Using `alias | sls -All "Get-"`. No result, because `sls` uses `toString` which is only the name column:

[image]

---

1. Using `alias | Out-String | sls -All "Get-"`. Only highlights

[image]

---

2. Using `alias | Where-Object {$_.Definition -like "*Get-Alias*"}`. A lot to write and requires knowing the column where the text is.

[image]

---

3. Using `alias | findstr "Get-"`. Works, but requires the use of a legacy executable that is not available on all PowerShell Core supported platforms. I want the code to work on all platforms without switches.

[image]

---

4. Write to a file and then pipe that to `Select-String`. Very inpractical.

...

---

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: `alias | oss | sls -All "Get-"`

Comment: Posting images of technical information like code or console commands and output, instead of formatted text, is the fastest way I've seen here other than spam for a question to be downvoted and then closed or ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to grep the objects as you see them displayed on your console, your first example using [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string?view=powershell-7.3) was going in the right direction except you were missing the [`-Stream` switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string?view=powershell-7.3#example-2-working-with-objects):

```
alias | Out-String -Stream | sls -All "Get-"
```

Or if you want to have it shorter, you can use the [built-in wrapper `oss`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_built-in_functions?view=powershell-7.3#oss):

```
alias | oss | sls -All "Get-"
```

Comment: Off topic, but it's funny where you placed your winter hat haha

Comment: @AbrahamZinala LOL not sure where else it could go :D

Comment: It's just funny seeing a fish with one xD

Comment: Nice; Worth pointing out that that `oss` arguably shouldn't be necessary, and that `Select-String` should _by default_ use the richly formatted string representation rather than the `.ToString()` value for non-string input objects, as suggested in [GitHub issue #10726](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10726).

Comment: @mklement0 ah yes I've seen this issue before. tbh I don't know if I agree, I don't really have an opinion on this topic as I believe it is the wrong tool to filter objects. I don't know which implications this could have if `Select-String` defaults to this. Building a proxy command that does this by default is also an easy alternative for anyone wanting to do this.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for pointing to that issue. It has some great suggestions :)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, yes, `Select-String` is  the wrong tool for _robustly_ filtering of objects _for programmatic use_. However, it _is_ the right tool for _quick-and-dirty_, _interactive_ use, and indeed I have a wrapper function for personal use that has become an indispensable tool for me. There's no reason _not_ to fix `Select-String` to work this way, given that (a) it is what users intuitively expect and (b) the current behavior is useless. Using Dmitrij's example: if `Select-String` worked that way, `get-alias | sls get-` would be a handy way to quickly view the aliases of interest.

Comment: this minor change would break things for folks using it the way it was designed, i.e.: `[Text.StringBuilder]::new('hello world') | sls hello` would no longer work. Not saying it's a bad idea but things like this need to be thought carefully imo moreso when the fix is adding a new command or having a wrapper... @mklement0

Comment: Fair point: that's an edge case that would break. `Select-String` is indeed designed for _strings_, as the name implies. But that doesn't mean that `.ToString()` is the right way to stringify non-string input. In fact, it is almost always unhelpful. To my mind, this change is a clear-cut [bucket 3](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/docs/dev-process/breaking-change-contract.md#bucket-3-unlikely-grey-area) change, even more so given that the use case at hand is to be avoided _in scripts_.